# Impeller Rendering Engine Causing Massive Latency and Memory Consumption

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator

I'm working on a Flutter project (sdk: '>=3.0.1 <4.0.0') for iOS (platform :ios, '13.0') and right after upgrading Flutter this morning I noticed that the iPhone simulator (Xcode 14.3) was using between 3-5gb of memory and my entire system was unusable as long as the simulator was running.

I have a 32GB Mac and when the simulator was onscreen (when minimized the system was performant and seemed fine) and running, my entire system was experiencing massive latency, lags, and performance issues. Scrolling through source, doing any kind of debugging, or really anything at all was extremely difficult due to the performance impact (VS Code for my IDE).

After spending several hours debugging what the heck was going on all of a sudden (this had never happened before the upgrade), I noticed in my debug console a line I hadn't seen before...

`"[VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(35)] Using the Impeller rendering backend."`

After some quick Googling and reading about how Impeller is apparently so awesome and incredible, I decided to turn it off and see what would happen. I added the following tag to my info.plist to disable it.

```
<key>FLTEnableImpeller</key>
  <false />
```

Low and behold to my delight, but certainly not surprise, everything went back to "normal" and I was able to actually scroll through a source file while the simulator was running my project on screen at the same time! Almost like I wasn't in the early 1990's anymore working on my 386... Simulator memory was at around 140-500mb at most.

My question is, how can I enable Impeller and still be able to use the rest of my system at the same time? Has anyone else experienced this behavior or had a similar issues with Flutter/Impeller after upgrading or at any point? Would love to hear peoples thoughts on this.

Comment: Suffering the same issue. Added as a issue on Github / Flutter. I got 8gb ram so i thought it was finally time for an upgrade of my computer but when switched back from impeller everything works great again.

Comment: A workaround until this issue is adressed, use:
flutter run --no-enable-impeller

to run when running on the simulator. Instead of changing the info.plist, then when you build the app for iOS impeller is still enabled.

when i've tried with flutter run --release on a real device impeller works great.

Comment: Thanks @broderbluff for the workaround above (I'll give it a try) and for adding an issue with Github. If you are able to share the issue you logged, I'd love to follow it and upvote it too.

Comment: Took my time to comment :/ :p

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/127482

Here is issue on github.

Comment: Same latency issue here. I opened an issue on GitHub https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/128391

Comment: When I first encountered the problem, I thought the problem occurred because of my weak graphics card. Can you confirm if you have a good graphics card or not?

Answer (score -2):

Change connectivity_plus to 1.2.0, it worked for me

```
Pubspec.yaml> connectivity_plus: ^1.2.0
```

Comment: Please explain the comment further to solve the problem mentioned in the question or mention the relationship between this package and the problem mentioned in the question.
Also, I'm using the latest package version and still having the same issue.